# Retrieving only unique records with multiple requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, activerecord, filtering

I have this "heavy_rotation" filter I'm working on. Basically it grabs tracks from our database based on certain parameters (a mixture of listens_count, staff_pick, purchase_count, to name a few)

An xhr request is made to the filter_tracks controller action. In there I have a flag to check if it's "heavy_rotation". I will likely move this to the model (cos this controller is getting fat)... Anyway, how can I ensure (in a efficient way) to not have it pull the same records? I've considered an offset, but than I have to keep track of the offset for every query. Or maybe store track.id's to compare against for each query? Any ideas? I'm having trouble thinking of an elegant way to do this.

Maybe it should be noted that a limit of 14 is set via Javascript, and when a user hits "view more" to paginate, it sends another request to filter_tracks.

Any help appreciated! Thanks!

```
def filter_tracks

    params[:limit] ||= 50
    params[:offset] ||= 0
    params[:order] ||= 'heavy_rotation'

    # heavy rotation filter flag
    heavy_rotation ||= (params[:order] == 'heavy_rotation')

    @result_offset = params[:offset]
    @tracks = Track.ready.with_artist

    params[:order] = "tracks.#{params[:order]}" unless heavy_rotation

    if params[:order]
      order = params[:order]
      order.match(/artist.*/){|m|
        params[:order] = params[:order].sub /tracks\./, ''
      }
      order.match(/title.*/){|m|
        params[:order] = params[:order].sub /tracks.(title)(.*)/i, 'LOWER(\1)\2'
      }
    end

    searched = params[:q] && params[:q][:search].present?

    @tracks = parse_params(params[:q], @tracks)

    @tracks = @tracks.offset(params[:offset])

    @result_count = @tracks.count

    @tracks = @tracks.order(params[:order], 'tracks.updated_at DESC').limit(params[:limit]) unless heavy_rotation

    # structure heavy rotation results
    if heavy_rotation

      puts "*" * 300

      week_ago = Time.now - 7.days
      two_weeks_ago = Time.now - 14.days
      three_months_ago = Time.now - 3.months


      # mix in top licensed tracks within last 3 months
      t = Track.top_licensed
      tracks_top_licensed = t.where(
        "tracks.updated_at >= :top", 
        top: three_months_ago).limit(5)


      # mix top listened to tracks within last two weeks
      tracks_top_listens = @tracks.order('tracks.listens_count DESC').where(
        "tracks.updated_at >= :top",
        top: two_weeks_ago)
        .limit(3)  


      # mix top downloaded tracks within last two weeks
      tracks_top_downloaded = @tracks.order("tracks.downloads_count DESC").where(
        "tracks.updated_at >= :top",
        top: two_weeks_ago)
        .limit(2)


      # mix in 25% of staff picks added within 3 months
      tracks_staff_picks = Track.ready.staff_picks.
        includes(:artist).order("tracks.created_at DESC").where(
        "tracks.updated_at >= :top", 
        top: three_months_ago)
        .limit(4)

      @tracks = tracks_top_licensed + tracks_top_listens + tracks_top_downloaded + tracks_staff_picks


    end

    render partial: "shared/results"
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think seeking an "elegant" solution is going to yield many diverse opinions, so I'll offer one approach and my reasoning. In my design decision, I feel that in this case it's optimal and elegant to enforce uniqueness on query intersections by filtering the returned record objects instead of trying to restrict the query to only yield unique results. As for getting contiguous results for pagination, on the other hand, I would store offsets from each query and use it as the starting point for the next query using instance variables or sessions, depending on how the data needs to be persisted.

Here's a `gist` to my refactored version of your code with a solution implemented and comments explaining why I chose to use certain logic or data structures: https://gist.github.com/femmestem/2b539abe92e9813c02da

`#filter_tracks` holds a hash map `@tracks_offset` which the other methods can access and update; each of the query methods holds the responsibility of adding its own offset key to `@tracks_offset`.

`#filter_tracks` also holds a collection of track id's for tracks that already appear in the results.

If you need persistence, make `@tracks_offset` and `@track_ids` sessions/cookies instead of instance variables. The logic should be the same. If you use sessions to store the offsets and id's from results, remember to clear them when your user is done interacting with this feature.

See below. Note, I refactored your `#filter_tracks` method to separate the responsibilities into 9 different methods: `#filter_tracks`, `#heavy_rotation`, `#order_by_params`, `#heavy_rotation?`, `#validate_and_return_top_results`, and `#tracks_top_licensed`... `#tracks_top_<whatever>`. This will make my notes easier to follow and your code more maintainable.

```
def filter_tracks
  # Does this need to be so high when JavaScript limits display to 14?
  @limit ||= 50

  @tracks_offset ||= {}
  @tracks_offset[:default] ||= 0
  @result_track_ids ||= []

  @order ||= params[:order] || 'heavy_rotation'

  tracks = Track.ready.with_artist
  tracks = parse_params(params[:q], tracks)
  @result_count = tracks.count

  # Checks for heavy_rotation filter flag
  if heavy_rotation? @order
    @tracks = heavy_rotation
  else
    @tracks = order_by_params
  end

  render partial: "shared/results"
end
```

All `#heavy_rotation` does is call the various query methods. This makes it easy to add, modify, or delete any one of the query methods as criteria changes without affecting any other method.

```
def heavy_rotation
  week_ago = Time.now - 7.days
  two_weeks_ago = Time.now - 14.days
  three_months_ago = Time.now - 3.months

  tracks_top_licensed(date_range: three_months_ago, max_results: 5) +
  tracks_top_listens(date_range: two_weeks_ago, max_results: 3) +
  tracks_top_downloaded(date_range: two_weeks_ago, max_results: 2) +
  tracks_staff_picks(date_range: three_months_ago, max_results: 4)
end
```

Here's what one of the query methods looks like. They're all basically the same, but with custom SQL/ORM queries. You'll notice that I'm not setting the `:limit` parameter to the number of results that I want the query method to return. This would create a problem if one of the records returned is duplicated by another query method, like if the same track was returned by `staff_picks` and `top_downloaded`. Then I would have to make an additional query to get another record. That's not a wrong decision, just one I didn't decide to do.

```
def tracks_top_licensed(args = {})
  args = @default.merge args
  max = args[:max_results]
  date_range = args[:date_range]

  # Adds own offset key to #filter_tracks hash map => @tracks_offset
  @tracks_offset[:top_licensed] ||= 0

  unfiltered_results = Track.top_licensed
    .where("tracks.updated_at >= :date_range", date_range: date_range)
    .limit(@limit)
    .offset(@tracks_offset[:top_licensed])

  top_tracks = validate_and_return_top_results(unfiltered_results, max)

  # Add offset of your most recent query to the cumulative offset
  # so triggering 'view more'/pagination returns contiguous results
  @tracks_offset[:top_licensed] += top_tracks[:offset]

  top_tracks[:top_results]
end
```

In each query method, I'm cleaning the record objects through a custom method `#validate_and_return_top_results`. My validator checks through the record objects for duplicates against the `@track_ids` collection in its ancestor method `#filter_tracks`. It then returns the number of records specified by its caller.

```
def validate_and_return_top_results(collection, max = 1)
  top_results = []
  i = 0 # offset incrementer

  until top_results.count >= max do
    # Checks if track has already appeared in the results
    unless @result_track_ids.include? collection[i].id

      # this will be returned to the caller
      top_results << collection[i]

      # this is the point of reference to validate your query method results
      @result_track_ids << collection[i].id
    end
    i += 1
  end
  { top_results: top_results, offset: i }
end
```